# a program using dynamic memory allocation to take a string of unknown size in c

Tags: c, input, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am making a program where user will input a string of unknown size,if the user input "END" then the program will terminate, otherwise, it will ask for another string and another
As the size of the string is unknown, I used dynamic memory allocation to take the string of unknown size
Heres what I have tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() 
{
    bool on = true;
    char *string;
    while(on)
    {
        string = malloc(sizeof(char));
        int i;
        for (i = 0;; i++)
        {
            int n;
            n = getchar();
            if (n == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                string = realloc(string, sizeof(char));
                string[i] = (char)n;
            }
        }
        string[i] = '\0';
        if (strcmp(string, "END") == 0)
        {
            on = false;
        }
        printf("Len: [%i],String = %s\n",i+1,string);
        free(string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but if i input a string of size more than 25 or so, the program crashes, it gives me this output

```
0 [main] get_the_line_dynamically 1056 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to get_the_line_dynamically.exe.stackdump
```

but, what's wrong with this code??

Comment: Your `realloc` call is not making the buffer any bigger; you are passing in `sizeof(char)`, thereby requesting "please resize this to 1", which it already is.

Comment: You may want something like ```realloc(string, sizeof(char) * n);```

Comment: You probably wanted `realloc(string, i + 2)`.  For instance, suppose that you read exactly one character of input. In that case, the loop body executes once with `i == 0`. The buffer already has size 1, and so it has to be bumped up to 2: two bytes are needed to hold the character at `string[0]` and the null terminating byte at `string[1]`.

Comment: @ShahzadIftikhar `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: @SergeyA While that is true, it can be a good idea to use `sizeof(char)` instead of `1`. It's easier to change the code to some other character type like `wchar_t` later.

Comment: Use the type `size_t` for `i`, not `int`, and watch out for it wrapping around or getting too large. It's a good idea to check the return value of `malloc` and `realloc` for null.

Comment: @Kaz, no, this is not a good idea to use `sizeof(char)` as it makes nothing easier - you will still have to find all the places where `sizeof(char)` is taken and figure out if you need to change them or not. If you want to future-proof your program, you can use `sizeof(*string)`.

Comment: @SergeyA That is indeed best; don't proliferate the type name; refer to declared identifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`realloc()` allocates the size you specify and when the size is increased it copies data from the original allocation to the new allocation, then returns the old data to the heap.  It is not *incremental* the size you pass it is the absolute size, not the size *increase*.

As such you need :

```
string = realloc( string, i + 2 ) ;
```

However incrementing in single bytes is horribly inefficient, requiring an allocation, data copy, and free for every single byte.  The normal process is to increment the *capacity* in larger chunks, and increase the allocation only then the current capacity is exceeded.  So you might have:

```c
#define STRING_CAPACITY_INCREMENT 32
size_t string_capacity = STRING_CAPACITY_INCREMENT ;
char* string = malloc( string_capacity ) ;
```

Then:

```c
// If insufficient capacity for new character plus NUL...
if( i + 2 > string_capacity )
{
    string_capacity += STRING_CAPACITY_INCREMENT ;
    string = realloc(string, string_capacity );
}
string[i] = (char)n;
```

That will improve time performance, but in case you are concerned about memory usage, bear in mind that memory allocations are 8 byte aligned, so single byte increments save nothing compared with a capacity increment of 8 for example. Also for that reason the increment should be a multiple of 8 too.

In some cases you might chose an exponential capacity increase such as doubling: 8, 16, 32, 64 etc. to some reasonable limit whereafter it becomes linear.  That may be better in terms of balancing performance and memory usage if you have a lot of small strings and just a few long ones.

Comment: spelling note: "bear in mind', literally, to _carry_ in one's mind.

Comment: @TimRandall fixed - more typo than ignorance. Good spot.

Comment: Single byte increments do save something: code complexity. The growth is handled by a single `realloc`  line, issued unconditionally.

Comment: @Kaz True, in this trivial example, it is less complex, and performance is not an issue perhaps if the input is manual and the strings are short.  However in any significant application it would not be a habit you'd want to apply universally.  The issue if complexity is easily resolved by for example a string buffer struct type and function to wrap the extension. But really, this is why C++ exists.